# Search and Sort with MySQL Data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning PHP, I create a page to show my data table in MySQL. I want to paging, searching, sorting with that data.

I write some conditions to search and sort. But it's not working. My Paging seem work fine.

```
<?php
        echo "<form action = 'Activiti_Data_Table_Detail.php' method = 'post'>";
        echo "<input type = 'text' name = 'valueToSearch' placeholder = 'Value to search'><br><br>";
        echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'search' value = 'Filter'><br><br>";
        echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'ASC' value = 'Ascending'><br><br>";
        echo "<input type = 'submit' name = 'DESC' value = 'Descending'><br><br>";

        echo "<table id = 'datatable' border='1'>";
        echo "<thead>";
        echo "<tr>";    
        echo "<th>ID_</th>";   
        echo "<th>PROC_INST_ID_</th>";    
        echo "<th>BUSINESS_KEY_</th>";
        echo "<th>PROC_DEF_ID_</th>";
        echo "<th>START_TIME_</th>";
        echo "<th>END_TIME_</th>";
        echo "<th>DURATION_</th>";
        echo "<th>START_USER_ID_</th>";
        echo "<th>START_ACT_ID_</th>";
        echo "<th>END_ACT_ID_</th>";
        echo "<th>SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_</th>";
        echo "<th>DELETE_REASON_</th>";
        echo "<th>TENANT_ID_</th>";
        echo "<th>NAME_</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</thead>";

        //connect to database
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123456","activiti") or die(mysqli_connect_errno());

        //define how many results per page
        $result_per_page = 10;

        //number of results stored in database
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
        $num_of_results = mysqli_num_rows($result); //225

        //determine number of total pages available
        $number_of_pages = ceil($num_of_results/$result_per_page);

        //determine current page is on
        if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
            $page  = 1;
        } else {
            $page = $_GET['page'];
        }

        //determine the SQL LIMIT starting number for the result on the displaying page
        $this_page_first_result = ($page - 1) * $result_per_page;

        if(isset($_POST['search']) & isset($_POST['ASC'])){
            $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst WHERE concat(ID_, PROC_INST_ID_, PROC_DEF_ID_, START_TIME_, END_TIME_, DURATION_) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'
                    ORDER BY END_TIME_ ASC LIMIT" .$this_page_first_result . ',' . $result_per_page;

        } elseif (isset($_POST['search']) & isset($_POST['DESC'])) {
            $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst WHERE concat(ID_, PROC_INST_ID_, PROC_DEF_ID_, START_TIME_, END_TIME_, DURATION_) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'
                    ORDER BY END_TIME_ DESC LIMIT" .$this_page_first_result . ',' . $result_per_page;

        } elseif (isset($_POST['search'])) {
            $valueToSearch = $_POST['valueToSearch'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst WHERE concat(ID_, PROC_INST_ID_, PROC_DEF_ID_, START_TIME_, END_TIME_, DURATION_) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'
                    LIMIT" .$this_page_first_result . ',' . $result_per_page;

        } elseif (isset($_POST['ASC'])) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst  ORDER BY END_TIME_ ASC LIMIT" .$this_page_first_result . ',' . $result_per_page;

        } elseif (isset($_POST['DESC'])) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst  ORDER BY END_TIME_ DESC LIMIT" .$this_page_first_result . ',' . $result_per_page;

        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst LIMIT" .$this_page_first_result . ',' . $result_per_page;

        }

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<tbody>";
            echo "<tr>";

            echo "<td><a href='Data_Table_Detail.php' target='_blank'>" . $row['ID_'] . "</a></td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['PROC_INST_ID_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['BUSINESS_KEY_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['PROC_DEF_ID_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['START_TIME_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['END_TIME_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['DURATION_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['START_USER_ID_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['START_ACT_ID_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['END_ACT_ID_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['SUPER_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['DELETE_REASON_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['TENANT_ID_'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['NAME_'] . "</td>";

            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</form>";

        //display the links to the page
        for($page = 1; $page <= $number_of_pages; $page++) {
            echo '<a href="Activiti_Data_Table_Detail.php?page=' . $page . '">' . $page . '</a> ';
        }

        mysqli_close($con);           
    ?>
```

When I run this, it say: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result.
Can you help me? 
Thank you!

Comment: which query gets run? do you get the error for ALL queries?

Comment: that warning appear in my while loop, so I think these queries was wrong :( but I still have no idea how to fix

Comment: You have to check if your $sql variable aren't empty after your all if statements

Comment: before `$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);` add `exit($sql);` ~ report back what it prints

Comment: All of the queries above that have a `LIMIT` clause appear to be structured incorrectly as there seems to be no space after `LIMIT` so effectively it would be `LIMIT20,20` etc which should be `LIMIT 20,20` or whatever

Comment: Also: do not print `<tbody>` in the loop ( when it works ), put it before the loop just after `</thead>`

Comment: Onefinal point: Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection due to the unsanitised use of POST data in the sql queries. Consider using `prepared statements` instead - not too hard to learn and will save you much time in the future if your db is compromised

Comment: ok I fixed. Now it's work. But when I search or sort, it just show right result only first page, when I click to the next page, the result is still not searched or sorted. Can you help me a litte more?

Comment: what was the problem - the `LIMIT` ?

Comment: yeah I think so! when I search data, it's show right result on page but the paging is still show total page of my original data, not my search result data. And when I click any number paging, the result page will become original. Sorry because my bad English, I hope you can understand what I am saying :(

Comment: one thing to suggest about paging - rather than using the classic `LIMIT 10,10` etc you are better to use the ID ~ like `where id >9 limit 10` etc - when the table gets large this will be much, much quicker

Comment: thank you, I will noted it. But I'm still don't know how to fix my code like I say above.

Comment: Why work blind?  [`mysqli_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) will tell you exactly what the problem is!

Comment: where I should put this into my code?

Answer (score 0):

try change all your ifs for this:

```php
  $valueToSearch  = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['valueToSearch'] : '';
  $orderBy        = isset($_POST['ASC']) ? 'ORDER BY END_TIME_ ASC' : (isset($_POST['DESC']) ? 'ORDER BY END_TIME_ DESC' : '');

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM act_hi_procinst WHERE concat(ID_, PROC_INST_ID_, PROC_DEF_ID_, START_TIME_, END_TIME_, DURATION_) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' " . $orderBy . " LIMIT " . $this_page_first_result . ',' . $result_per_page;
```

Comment: It say: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result.

Comment: Sorry, I'm update the answer, try again please.
This error (mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result) this error may indicate that the SQL string is wrong, so to debug you can do ```die($ sql);``` before the ```mysqli_fetch_array``` line to see how the string is and what the error is